# PhpStorm's Extract Interface refactoring not working

Tags: refactoring, phpstorm

I'm trying to extract the interface from class using Context Menu on class name -> Refactor -> Extract interface.

- Dialog window appears where I enter the interface name and press the "Refactor" button.
- It looks for class usages and then nothing happens: no preview window opens, no new file with interface created.
- Just the dialog window continues to be shown and that's it.

This happens on MacOS, PhpStorm 2022.2 and 2021.2

What should I do to make it generate a new interface from the existing class?

Comment: **1)** First thing to try: `File | Invalidate Caches...` and restart the IDE. Let it reindex the project and try again. **2)** If still the same: try disabling all custom (not bundled by default) plugins, restart the IDE and try again -- one of the plugins may be causing issues (that may appear in unexpected places). Any difference?

Answer (score 0):

I tried to Invalidate Caches with different checked options and then with all checked options, but it doesn't solve problem
After that I removed all files from directories:

- Settings: ~/Library/Application Support/JetBrains/
- Plugins: ~/Library/Application Support/JetBrains/Plugins/
- Caches: ~/Library/Caches/JetBrains/
- Logs: ~/Library/Logs/JetBrains/

Problem was gone

Then I localized problem by restoring Plugins folder and trying to disable different plugins

At last it was "Yii2 Support" plugin unfortunately

Comment: *"At last it was "Yii2 Support" plugin unfortunately"* Yes, this plugin causes different kinds of issues. See this ticket, it has a link to some custom build that _may_ work better: https://github.com/nvlad/yii2support/issues/276